# JSF - unhandled faces messages prevent rerendering of view

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I work with JSF, RichCalendar and a4j. My problem: I want to rerender components of my website but if someone edits the date of one rich-calendar input field to '12.aa.2012' a FacesMessage is thrown, which is correct and good. Anyway my a4j-rerender-event did not get triggered due to unhandeld facesMessages. On my Tomcat-Console I get this errorMessage:

```
WARNUNG: There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
- Bitte ein gültiges Datum eingeben!
```

How can I handle this problem, I tried several ways to show the errorMessage and I can figure out how to show it, but there is still the warning and still the not triggered-rerender-event?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: here is the code to my question. As you can see after you select one of the radio buttons, one dateContainer will show up, for example 'admissionDateContainer'. If you change the value to 'asd', and select another choice, no rerendering of the related box happens, the choice will change but the wrong dateContainer will stay there ?!

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="caseTypeContainer" rendered="#{CaseController.isFallContainer}" styleClass="fieldContainer">
    <t:outputLabel for="caseType" styleClass="generalInputLabel" style="width:200px; float:left;" value="#{resources.labels['caseType']}:" title="#{resources.labels['caseType']}" />
    <h:selectOneRadio id="caseType" style="font-size:13px;" value="#{CaseController.caseType}" styleClass="radioButtonTableMasterdata inlineBlock">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{resources.labels['caseTypeDocAttrStationaer']}" itemLabel="#{resources.labels['caseTypeDocAttrStationaerLabel']}" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{resources.labels['caseTypeDocAttrAmbulant']}" itemLabel="#{resources.labels['caseTypeDocAttrAmbulant']}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{resources.labels['caseTypeDocAttrUnbekannt']}" itemLabel="#{resources.labels['caseTypeDocAttrUnbekannt']}"/>
    <a4j:support oncomplete="initializeFocusBlurEvents(); " event="onchange" reRender="captureDateContainerDiv, admissionDateContainerDiv, dischargeDateContainerDiv, messagesContainer, warnings"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGroup>
<t:div id="admissionDateContainerDiv">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="admissionDateContainer" rendered="#{CaseController.isCaseTypeStationaerOrAmbulant}" styleClass="fieldContainer  showDateInputWithTime">
        <t:outputLabel for="admissionDate" rendered="#{CaseController.isCaseTypeStationaer}" styleClass="generalInputLabel" style="width:200px;" value="#{resources.labels['caseAdmissionDateStationaer']}:" title="#{resources.labels['caseAdmissionDateStationaer']}" />
    <t:outputLabel for="admissionDate" rendered="#{CaseController.isCaseTypeAmbulant}" styleClass="generalInputLabel" style="width:200px;" value="#{resources.labels['caseAdmissionDateAmbulant']}:" title="#{resources.labels['caseAdmissionDateAmbulant']}" />
    <rich:calendar id="admissionDate" value="#{CaseController.caseContainerAdmissionDate}" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" enableManualInput="true" direction="auto">
        <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%" columnClasses="fake, width100 talign">
        <h:outputText value="{selectedDateControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
    <h:outputText value="{timeControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
    <h:outputText value="{todayControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
    </rich:calendar>
    <rich:message for="admissionDate"  />
</h:panelGroup>
</t:div>
<t:div id="messagesContainer" rendered="true"> 
    <p>Messages global</p>
<rich:messages global="true" />
</t:div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<rich:messages` or `<rich:message` to your page

Take a look at [rich:messages](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/messages.jsf?tab=usage&cid=142670) and [rich:message](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/message.jsf?c=message&tab=usage)

Also make sure that they are being `rendered` after your `button` is being clicked... add their ids or their wrapper (`@form` for example) ids to the `reRender` of your calendar

Comment: Thanks I read rich:message, rich:messages and tried lots of combinations of rerendering ... still no success. I added a code example, maybe that will help to find a solution.

Comment: for checking what wrong try re rendering @form or event bigger wrapper only (instead of multiple ids..)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, unfortuantely still no success. I added the form-id to the rerender-attribute of the select field. I can see the FacesMessage which is rendered. My last try is to look for the RichFaces-Calendar class and try to prevent the message-creation. That is worst way possible but I have no other idea. Where does the messages got created/thrown?